# Cloudfoundry - Can not access database when using vmc rails-console

Tags: cloud-foundry, rails-console

I have deployed a rails application (using rails 3.2.3. ruby 1.9.2), it's up and running and everything is working. Then I tried to manage it using rails console, as `vmc rails-console myapp`. The console can be connected but when I issue a command like `User.count` I get the following error:

```
User.count(0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` 
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error:
 MySQL server has gone away: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users`
```

It seems that the console can not access the database but caldecott is up and running and is bound to the mysql service according to `vmc apps`.

Anyone has ideas on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is something we are currently looking to resolve. In the interim, you can have ActiveRecord re-establish the connection by calling establish_connection on the Base class;

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
```

Dan

Comment: Just a follow-up: the issue has been fixed on CloudFoundry.com, and you should no longer need to run `ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection`.